# How to vertically stack blocks of an nD array?

Tags: matlab

I have a 5D array A and want to vertically stack the blocks
A(x,y,z,:,:) for all x, y and z. I have done the following:

```
    A = rand(128, 128, 64, 20, 3);
    a = 1; 
    for z = 1:Z
       for y = 1:Y
           for x = 1:X
               res(a:a+T-1,:) = squeeze(A(x,y,z,:,:));
               a = a + T;
           end
       end
    end
```

While correct, it appears that this computation is quite slow for my purpose.
Can anyone figure out how to achieve the same goal more efficiently?

Comment: By the way, if you just pre-allocate `res`, your code will be fast (relatively). Pre-allocate by including this before the first for loop: `res = -1*ones(128*128*64*20, 3)`. For a much faster alternative, see the answer below.

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on its left hand side, so that it comes off the unanswered question list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this via `reshape` and `permute`. First, understand how reshape works.

```
c = randi(9,[2 2 3])

c(:,:,1) =

     5     8
     2     6


c(:,:,2) =

     4     4
     5     1


c(:,:,3) =

     3     2
     2     3
```

Let us reshape c into a `2 x 6` matrix.

```
ans =

     5     8     4     4     3     2
     2     6     5     1     2     3
```

Now a `6 x 2` matrix.

```
ans =

     5     4
     2     1
     8     3
     6     2
     4     2
     5     3
```

See that while creating the reshaped matrix, MATLAB starts traversing the first dimension of `c` and puts it along the first dimension (i.e. along rows in the first column) in the reshaped matrix. Specifically,

```
c(1,1,1) = 5
c(2,1,1) = 2
c(1,2,1) = 8
c(2,2,1) = 6
c(1,1,2) = 4
c(2,1,2) = 5 % stop since you would have filled 6 rows
```

which forms the first column of the reshaped matrix.

Coming back to your example,

the first column of the reshaped matrix will be along the rows of your `20x3` submatrix i.e. the fourth dimension. The first row will be along your columns of your `20x3` submatrix i.e. along the fifth dimension. However, when you traverse from `(1,1)` to `(1,2)` in your reshaped matrix, you will have to accomodate all the elements from your first three dimensions (i.e. `128, 128, 64`, why?, because you first traverse your `x` dimension, then `y` and then finally `z` dimension). So your answer is, you want to move along dimensions: `4,1,2,3,5` in that order.

## Answer:

```
sz_A = size(A);
p = sz_A(4)*prod(sz_A(1:3))
reshaped_A = reshape(permute(A,[4, 1, 2, 3, 5]), [p size(A,5)])
```

Comment: This is very nice! Thank you for your time. Following your
explanations, I have been also able to revert form reshaped_A to A
using A_back = permute(reshape(reshaped_A, sz_A(4), sz_A(1), sz_A(2), sz_A(3),
sz_A(5)), [2 3 4 1 5]);